# Can't save contacts in Sony Xperia

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, sim-card

I have a *Sony Xperia* with Android OS 4.0.4. Until recently it worked fine but now my SIM contacts are all gone. I can't save in sim either.

While saving in contacts I *used* to get option whether to save on SIM or on phone ­– but now I don't get the SIM access: this options simply no longer shows up. I tried it with another SIM, but the problem persists.

Comment: Is there anything you changed recently? Some updates? Some configuration changes? Is the option gone completely, or did it just cease working? Any error message displayed?

Comment: No error message, I just don't get the option to save on SIM. Earlier I got a drop down list to select sim or phone.

Comment: OK, I've edited your question to point that out. Still open: did you change anything (configuration, updates, apps) between "it worked" and "option disappeared"? Any other information which might prove helpful for finding the culprit?

Comment: Don't think I did anything silly. I just casually used the phone to play games, I might have changed something on the setting in between, i can't remember.

Comment: Without any clear indicator, a factory-reset is the only thing coming to my mind. But maybe someone else turns up with a better answer. Good luck!

Comment: my be you have removed contact-provider app or try `*#*#INFO#*#*` on your dial-pad flow phone information for copying sim contact

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem to save the contact on the contact list 
they said you have to **clear data** of 
 ***Setting->App ->All ->Contacts*** 
then **restart** the phone.
I tried it, it worked,
but I've to do it **everytime** I save a new contact?!!!

Answer (score 0):

Question asked 7 year ago. Sim is old. Those sim can save 256 contacts only.

Comment: Something else is at play here. If SIM can't hold any more contacts the phone doesn't suddenly make all SIM contacts disappear. OP had this problem.

Comment: @aliz, would you mind providing a link to where this question was answered previously?